# Compact set in R that is not convex?

Tags: compactness, convex-optimization

Just need an example. For example, the I know the set [0,1] is compact because it is obviously closed and bounded. But I have no idea how to test for convexity

Comment: Consider the set of inverse naturals (plus an additional point to make it compact..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example $K=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$. It is not convex, because the interval $[1,2]\not\subset K$, although its end are in $K$.

Comment: So this is based on the fact that the union of two compact sets is also compact right? Could you please briefly explain how you know it's not convex?

Comment: Please see my extended answer.

Comment: Or, since it is a closed subset of $[0,3]$, you can use that a closed subset of a compact set is compact.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Or compactness from the fact, that a finite union of compact sets is compact.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I understand now

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke That was already expressed above, hence my "Or, since..."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh,sorry! There appeared a loop in comments.

Answer (score 5):

A set is in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is convex if and only if the line segment between any two points in the set is contained within the set. In $\mathbb{R}$, that just means the set is connected, or in other words an interval. Any compact set that is not connected is not convex.

Answer (score 1):

Convex sets are connected.  The only connected subsets of the line are intervals.  The only compact connected subsets of the line are closed bounded intervals (including single points). Plenty of subsets of the line are compact but not convex (just take two points).